# Set custom UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to be able to set my `UIPickerView` to have 1 column and 10 rows. Within this column there is a title (`UILabel`) and an image beside it (the images are stars, from 1-3 stars being a possibility). I have put the images into an array called "showImages". I have put the `UILabels` into an `NSString` array called "currentNames". The indexes of both array correspond with each other. For some reason my code is not working when I implement

```
 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
    forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

and I believe this is because I am using "row" to index the arrays which is incorrect. Does anyone know how I could do this properly? Thanks in advance, the rest of my code is below.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
    forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

NSString *imageName= [imageNames objectAtIndex:row];

if(component == 0)
{
NSString *imageName= [imageNames objectAtIndex:row];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];        
        temp.frame = CGRectMake(120, 15,70, 27);

    UILabel *channelLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-80, 0, 320, 60)];
    channelLabel.text = [currentLottoNames objectAtIndex:row];
    channelLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    channelLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    channelLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    channelLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0,1);

    UIView *tmpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 60)];

    [tmpView insertSubview:channelLabel atIndex:0];
    [tmpView insertSubview:temp atIndex: 1];
      i++;
      return tmpView;
     }
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Do you get any errors, or do you just not see what you expect to see?

Comment: I dropped your code into a test app and it worked fine for me. The only thin I had to change was to delete the i++ since it wouldn't compile with that. Have you logged imageNames and currentLottoNames inside the pickerView:viewForRow: method to see if they contain what you think they do?

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for doing that, I really appreciate it. I made the change (still not working) and I forgot to note in the question why it wasn't actually working. The reason is because as soon as I trying scrolling to the bottom and get close to the bottom, it crashes saying its index out of bounds. This is why I said the way I am indexing the arrays may not be correct. If you do an nslog you will see that the "row" from the function that is being passed into the array is not always how it should. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks again

Comment: Are you implementing pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:? You should be, and it should return [imageNames count] or [currentLottoNames count] both of which should be the same. If that is implemented correctly, then "row" shouldn't ever be out of bounds.

Comment: @rdelmar no I am doing it from - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow. How would it work from numberOfRows? Doesn't it need to itterate in the place where the subviews will be presented? I can post the code from numberOfRows if you need it. Thanks again

Comment: No, I don't mean to do what you posted from that method, just are you implementing pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:. That method will determine how many times  pickerView:viewForRow: is called. You simply  put "return [imageNames count];" in that method, nothing else.

Comment: @rdelmar Ahh yes I have done that from before. Again if I debug I feel like the issue is coming from "row" from which I retrieve from (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow (NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view when I index the image array that way. What do you think? Thanks again

Comment: I don't know how that could be wrong -- the row parameter being passed in should go from 0 to [imageNames count] - 1, so it should never be out of range. If you log row does it give you a number higher than [imageNames count] - 1? You should probably log [imageNames count] in the pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent: method too, to make sure it's giving you what you think it is. Why don't you post the rest of the code in this class.

Comment: @rdelmar Ahhh one of my arrays was shorter than the other, missing an object inside. Thank so much for helping me debug! if you want to post your last comment as an answer, I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how that could be wrong -- the row parameter being passed in should go from 0 to [imageNames count] - 1, so it should never be out of range. If you log row does it give you a number higher than [imageNames count] - 1? You should probably log [imageNames count] in the pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent: method too, to make sure it's giving you what you think it is.